# vector of strings error

Tags: c++, string, vector, substr

there is an error in the following code that I don't get , I tried debugging but it wasn't useful .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int n;

        string s ;
        cin>>s;

        vector<string> v ;

        for (int i=0;i<s.size()-1;i+=2)
        {
            v[i]=s.substr(i,2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: *Always* include the error messages you get in the question. And `#include <vector>`

Comment: You must resize the vector. You can't access an element that is out of its range.

Comment: thank you , I added #include <vector> but still the same result and there isn't an error shown when I run it just takes a lot of time to run before it is terminated without returning the result ( when i add a cout somthing in the end of the program) and when I debug there is a notification saying "Program received signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault." .

Comment: I resized the vector and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple issues:

1. Missing `#include <vector>` - on some compiler it may work without it.
2. size of the vector is zero so operator[] leads to segmentation fault
3. `-1` in loop is not needed
4. even if size of vector is ok, indexing by `i` is not desired since it is incremented by 2, so you are skipping elements.

So it should go like this:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<s.size(); i+=2)
{
    v.push_back(s.substr(i,2));
}
```

Comment: 1. I added it but nothing changed.
2. I think this is the problem , in fact I get segmentation fault when I debug , however I resized the vector (  vector<string> v[100] ) but still nothing changed .
3. -1 is needed because I take 2 characters in each iteration , so the last iteration takes 2 characters starting with the one before the last character.
4. I am skipping elements , it's true , but I will fill them later in the program(I just put a part of the program where I have a problem).

I tried your suggestion and it worked.(Note : doesn't work if the vector is resized)